# Jax ws web service

Tags: java, web-services

This is my server side code:

```
package com.son;   
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class Calculator1 {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b);
    }

    public int sub(int a, int b) {
        return (a - b);
    }

}
```

This is my publisher code.

```
package com.son.endpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import com.son.Calculator;
import com.son.Calculator1;

public class CalcEndpointPublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8089/CalcWS/Calculator1",
                    new Calculator1());
    }
 }
```

After this I have used wsgen command.

This is, my client code

```
package com.son.client;
import com.son.Calculator1;
import com.son.Calculator1Service;
public class CalcClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 67;
        int b = 898;
        Calculator1Service calcService = new Calculator1Service();
        Calculator1 calc = calcService.getCalculator1Port();
        System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + calc.add(a, b));
        System.out.println(a + " - " + b + " = " + calc.sub(a, b));
    }
}
```

I am getting the answer. My senior is asking how to pass an object, or how we can pass n number of values, please tell me how to code, as I am new in this, and also tell the code please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that methods in your `Calculator1` class should be `static`:

```
public class Calculator1 {

    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b);
    }

    public static int sub(int a, int b) {
        return (a - b);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i am asking how i can pass n number of values,means if the client want to add many numbers what i should do

Answer (score 0):

Use varargs in Calculator1 class

```
    public class Calculator1 {

    public static int add(Integer...args){

    int i=0;
    for (Integer integer : args) {
        i+=integer;
    }
    return i;
    }
   //same for your sub method
    }
```

You can pass any number of arguments like this:

```
    calc.add(10,11,12,13);
```